# Number of one one mappings

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations

If we have a set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ . How many one-to-one mappings $f : A \to A$ can be defined so that $f(i) \ne i$. 
How do we write the possible cases for the function definition to simultaneously fulfill the given criteria? I tried writing down, but cannot reach to an answer.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion: $5! - 5 \times 4! + 10 \times 3! - 10 \times 2! + 5 \times 1! - 0! = 34$

Comment: Have a look at [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Have a look at this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/144766).

Comment: The question does not make sense as stated.  Did you mean mappings $f:A \to A$?  Also, please edit your question to show your own attempt at the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An injective mapping $f:A \to A$ is a permutation of its elements.  Since $|A| = 5$, there are $5!$ such mappings.  From these, we must exclude those with one or more fixed points.

There are $\binom{5}{k}$ ways to select $k$ fixed points and $(5 - k)!$ ways to permute the remaining elements.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of injective mappings $f:A \to A$ with no fixed points is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{5} \binom{5}{0}(5 - k)! = 5! - \binom{5}{1}4! + \binom{5}{2}3! - \binom{5}{3}2! - \binom{5}{4}1! + \binom{5}{5}0! = 44$$

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to work out the number of permutations without fixed points.
Since any permutation have the form of disjoint cycles,what you need to do is to counting the number of different cyclic formats ——without 1-cycle.
here I use "cyclic formats " to express the number of cycles and the length of each cycle.For example:$(1,2)(3,4,5)and(1,3)(2,4,5)$have the same "cyclic formats " .
One format : $(2+3)$ the number is : $10\times2=20$
Here $(2+3)$ means the permutation like $(1,2)(3,4,5)$
Another : $(5)$: the number is : $5!\div5=24$
Here $(5)$ means the permutation like $(1,2,3,4,5)$
So the number should be$$20+24=44$$

Comment: Well yeah the question is f:A-->A  I am a beginner at permutations so how is the number of cyclic formats calculated? I wasnt able to understand..

Comment: @user153175 First you should know that permutatons can be wrote as products of disjoint cycles in a unique way. And  I use "cyclic formats " to express the number of cycles and the length of each cycle.For example:(1,2)(3,4,5)and(1,3)(2,4,5)have the same  "cyclic formats " .Mabye it's not the common phrase for this meaning,but,I forgot it,aaha.

Comment: and"2+3"means the permutation like"(1,2)(3,4,5) "while"5"means permutation like"(1,2,3,4,5)"

Answer (score 0):

The mappings you seek for are called **derangements** (see [Derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) at Wikipedia) and their number is the **subfactorial** $$!n$$ of the set's cardinality $n$.

Subfactorials are described as the [sequence A000166](https://oeis.org/A000166) in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).